# How to animate text and set max width and height using canvas javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, animation, canvas

I need the text that displays to be animated. Maybe it can fade in and move locations. Also I need to set a max width and height for the shapes because some of them are too big. Also if instead of the shapes being random colors, if there is a way I can set an array of colors to choose from.

```js
function makeTitle() {
    //generate the title for your masterpiece
    var lines = [
        'Meditative', 'Objective', 'Reflective', ['Ellipses', 'Tranformation', 'State', 'Emotion', 'Composition'], ['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V']];
        var title = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * lines[i].length);
            title += lines[i][random] + ' ';
        };
        return (title);
    }

    function artHandler() {
        var title = makeTitle();
        
        var canvas = document.getElementById('artCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        
        fillBackgroundColor(canvas, context);
        
        drawText(canvas, context, title);
        
        var num = 10;
        while( num --> 0 ) {
         drawCircle(canvas, context);
         drawRect(canvas, context);
            drawTriangle(canvas, context);
   drawShape(canvas, context);
   drawCir(canvas, context);
        }
        
    }

 function getBackgroundColor() {
     return "rgb("+[
         Math.round(Math.random()*0xFF),
         Math.round(Math.random()*0xFF),
         Math.round(Math.random()*0xFF)
        ].join(",")+")";
    }

    function fillBackgroundColor(canvas, context) {
        
        var bgColor = getBackgroundColor();
        context.fillStyle = bgColor;
        context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        
    }

    function degreesToRadians(degrees) {
        return (degrees * Math.PI) / 180;
    }
    // Draws a circle at a random location
    function drawCircle(canvas, context) {
        var radius = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40);
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, degreesToRadians(360), true);
        context.fillStyle = getBackgroundColor();
        context.fill();
    }

    function drawText(canvas, context, title) {
        context.fillStyle = getBackgroundColor();
        context.font = 'bold 1em sans-serif';
        context.textAlign = 'right';
        context.fillText(title, canvas.width - 20, canvas.height - 40);
    }

    function drawRect(canvas, context) {
        context.fillStyle = getBackgroundColor();
        context.fillRect(Math.random()*canvas.width, Math.random()*canvas.height,Math.random()*100,Math.random()*100);
    }
    
    function drawTriangle(canvas, context) {
        context.fillStyle = getBackgroundColor();

        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(Math.random()*canvas.width, Math.random()*canvas.height);
        context.lineTo(Math.random()*canvas.width, Math.random()*canvas.height);
        context.lineTo(Math.random()*canvas.width, Math.random()*canvas.height);
        context.fill();

    }
 function drawShape(canvas, context) {
        context.fillStyle = getBackgroundColor();

        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(Math.random()*canvas.width, Math.random()*canvas.height);
        context.lineTo(Math.random()*canvas.width, Math.random()*canvas.height);
        context.lineTo(Math.random()*canvas.width, Math.random()*canvas.height);
  context.lineTo(Math.random()*canvas.width, Math.random()*canvas.height);
  context.lineTo(Math.random()*canvas.width, Math.random()*canvas.height);
        context.fill();

    }
 
   function drawCir(canvas, context) {
        var radius = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40);
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, degreesToRadians(180), true);
        context.fillStyle = getBackgroundColor();
        context.fill();
    } 
    
    
   // window.onload = function() {
        var button = document.getElementById('artButton');
        button.onclick = artHandler;
    //}
```

```html
<form>
<input type='button' id='artButton' value='New Masterpiece'>
</form>
<canvas width='1200' height='600' id='artCanvas'></canvas>
​
```

Answer (score 1):

**Animate / FadeIn text:** Create a span element with your text and set it position:absolute and use [CSS animation](http://www.chrisbuttery.com/articles/fade-in-fade-out-with-javascript/) to both move the span and change the span opacity (fading).

**Shape size:** You are already setting each shape's max size -- your max size is the number you are multiplying with `Math.random()` (eg. canvas.width, canvas.height)

*Keeping shapes inside the canvas:* If you want contained shapes just reduce the multipliers. For non-circles, make sure all vertices are inside the canvas area: `0<vertexX<canvas.width` and `0<vertexY<canvas.height`.  For circles: `centerX-radius>0 && centerX+radius<canvas.width && centerY-radius>0 && centerY+radius<canvas.height`.

**Fixed Color Palette:** Create an array of your desired colors and select a color from the array with `fillStyle=parseInt(Math.random()*(colorArray.length))`

Comment: `parseInt(Math.random()*(colorArray.length-1))` -> `parseInt(Math.random()*colorArray.length)` or the last index will never be used since Math.random is in the range [0,1>.